# Debugging CiviRules Error

Tags: civirules, debugging

I am getting the error triggered by CiviRule and the error can be seen from the CiviRule Logger below. This rule is triggered when a new contact is created. This rule works if I create the contact from the UI but when I use the APIs it will fail.

Any help is appreciated.

**Error on CiviRuleLogger**

```
2018-09-07 00:12    error   Rule: 'Volunteer Interest Adding Rule' with id 3 failed for contact 503 because of Failed to execute rule   
Array
(
    [line] => 77
    [file] => /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/ext/civirules-master/CRM/CivirulesActions/Generic/Api.php
    [exception_message] => Civirules api action exception: Suppressed sending e-mail to: James. API call: Email.send with params: from_name="Voiddeck Ventures", from_email="
```

xxx@dummy.com", template_id="65", location_type_id="3", alternative_receiver_address="", cc="xxx@dummy.com", bcc="", file_on_case="", contact_id="503"
        [rule_title] => Volunteer Interest Adding Rule
        [original_error] => Error on {file} (Line {line})

```
{exception_message}
    [reason] => Failed to execute rule
)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange!  I've noticed that your error message includes potentially personal information (an email address).  You could edit the message to remove but unfortunately StackExchange keeps a full edit history so you may want to delete this message and repost it as a new question without any personal information.